# Check if parameter in URL is specific id

Tags: php, sql

I want to create functions for editing tables.

But I have more form which go to the same PHP page so when submit is sent I send a parameter in the URL like this `php/edit.php?id=website` and in the PHP code I want to check the ID in the URL so the function executes.

Here is the PHP code where I try to confirm the `ID` and then execute the function

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_GET['id']) == "website" {
    include('config.php');
    $sql2 = "UPDATE tblWebsite SET websiteNaam='".$_POST["websitenaam"]."' WHERE websiteId=".$_POST["websiteid"]."";

    if($db->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        header('Location: /bvdo/pages.php');
        } else {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $db->error."');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Good to note the function is working because if I remove the `&& isset($_GET['id']) == "website"` the database is updating with new values.

Comment: You don't close the first bracket in the if and the isset function will never return "website"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine isset and a compare. Also, you are missing a closing bracket in your if statement. What you probably want is this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == "website") {
    // Do something
}
```

**Explanation:**

With `isset($var)` you check if the variable `$var` was initialized anywhere (if it was set). If the variable was set, isset returns true, otherwise it returns false. So what you are effectively comparing is if `true == "website"`, and that is obviously never the case.

With `$var2 == "a string"` you check if your `$var` equals a string.

You can't mix them up, but check them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding complication to code, why don't you split save the id to hidden input and get it along with the $_POST['id'].

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST['id']) == "website" {
include('config.php');
$sql2 = "UPDATE tblWebsite SET websiteNaam='".$_POST["websitenaam"]."' WHERE websiteId=".$_POST["websiteid"]."";

if($db->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: /bvdo/pages.php');
    } else {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $db->error."');</script>";
    }
}
```

Now no need to worry about URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to clean up the code would be using a function that checks if the value is set. You can do it separately by checking *If function == your value*.

```
function getValue($id) {
  if (!isset($_GET[$id])) {
    return false;
  }
    return $_GET[$id];
  }

  if (getValue('id') == 'website') {
    include('config.php');
    $sql2 = "UPDATE tblWebsite SET websiteNaam='".$_POST["websitenaam"]."' 
    WHERE websiteId=".$_POST["websiteid"]."";

    if($db->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
      header('Location: /bvdo/pages.php');
    } else {
      echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" 
      . $db->error."');</script>";
    }
  }
}
```

**OR**

If you're looking for a one-liner to check the value of a variable you're not sure is set yet, this works:

```
if ((isset($variable) ? $variable : null) === $value) { }
```

The only possible downside is that if you're testing for `true`/`false` - `null` will be interpreted as equal to `false`.